# Traveling with 2 passports due to 3 month validity but visa on a different passport

Tags: visas, air-travel, china, dual-nationality

I have a bit of a convoluted question. 
My child has a Canadian and US Passport but travels with her Canadian passport since  it has a valid Chinese visa in it (we currently reside in China).
We are traveling to Spain this month but her Canadian passport has less than 3 months validity in it (Spain requires at least a 3 month validity in order to enter the country). She has a US passport with a longer validity period.

Would it be possible to EXIT China using her valid (but almost) expired Canadian passport with a valid China visa in it but then ENTER Spain with her American passport? Then EXIT Spain with the American Passport and RE-ENTER China with her Canadian passport and valid China visa?

In Essence:
Enter and Exit China with her almost expired Canadian Passport with Chinese visa
Enter and Exit Spain on her US passport with extended validity

Comment: There's a generic answer at https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/52101/1362, and I think Case 1 applies to your child.

Comment: Indeed, the other question answers your question, there will be no problem at all. If there are questions by the Spanish border people you can show the other passport as well but it is rather unlikely they will ask. Airline out may ask though, again both passports is a good option.